# How to have different selection color in QTableView?

Tags: qt, qtableview

Is it also possible to have two different select colors? And how do I do that? You know when you select a cell, the selected color can be set using a style sheet, but since I'm using table view, I was wondering if my view can query my model. For example I have a variable that stores the selection. If user selects a value "1", when he select a cell it will be red color, when he select "2" form the drop down list, when he selects the cell it will be blue. Is that possible?(my table will display two different selected cell colors at the same time, because the different colors are supposed to have a different meaning).

I have the following code but it returns a weird result.

my data() function:

```
if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
{
Return data[row][col];
}
Else if (role = Qt::DecorationRole)
{
//if ( selectionVar == 0 )
return QVariant(QColor(Qt::red));
//else if( .... )
}
```

The result is that i have red cells with check box in the cells.. I have no idea why this happened. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

You will have to implement your own [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) (or [`QItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html), if you don't want to use the current style. Thats however not recommended). There you can draw whatever you want to (including different selection colors). To use the special features of your model, either use custom Item roles or cast `QModelIndex::model()` to your own model implementation. (If more details are required, I can post more)

**EDIT** A simple example:

In your model do:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch(role) {
    //...
    case (Qt::UserRole + 3)://as an example, can be anything greater or equal to Qt::UserRole
        return (selectionVar == 0);
    //...
    }
}
```

Create the new Delegate class somewhere:

```
class HighlightDelegate : public QItemDelegate //QStyledItemDelegate would be better, but it wasn't able to change the styled highlight color there
{
public:
    HighlightDelegate(QObject *parent);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

HighlightDelegate::HighlightDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QItemDelegate(parent)
{}

void HighlightDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;

    if(index.model()->data(index, Qt::UserRole + 3).toBool())//same here
        opt.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::red);

    this->QItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
}
```

...and tell the view to use the delegate:

```
this->ui->itemView->setItemDelegate(new HighlightDelegate(this));
```

And thats it! This one (as you can see) was created using `QItemDelegate`. It seems to be impossible to create it with `QStyledItemDelegate`, since it will ignore the `QPalette::Highlight` (at least on windows).

Comment: Im sorry, I don't quite understand how to use the qitemdelegate, could u give a short example how do I implement it in my case? Thanks (y)

Comment: That looks good.. I tried it, but I'm still having this problem where checkbox like icons appear within my cells when I click. Also, when I switch my selection, the cells already selected also changes color when I click elsewhere. My code n results are as shown..

Comment: Table->setItemDelegate(new HighlightDelegate(this));   Table->setModel(grid);

Comment: This is what happens: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v483/dragonlancer/Mobile%20Uploads/443337E7-BE29-488B-9434-4D56578FC660.jpg

Comment: The selection seem to be pained somehow differently than the rest of the cell. If you make an empty version of `HighlightDelegate::paint` you'll still see the selection but nothing else. So basically your example above draws a rectangle on top of the selection, which is probably not ideal. I do wonder if there is a way to handle it so that the actual selection changes.